# How to make a single image change to different images based on where you hover over?

Tags: css, html

Is it possible to make an single image change based on where your mouse is positioned on the image?

If so, how I would I accomplish something like this?

Comment: Perhaps look at the concept of <map> an image. Then show a bit of code.

Answer (score 1):

Theres a concept of z-index which basically means that how the images are aligned in vertical space..You can stack all the imagesone above the other with only the topmost being visible..Then depending upon where the user is you can change the layering of the images on the fly.. But without any code its a bit difficult to know where are you stuck/what have you tried?